# Regex for validating email and add dot symbol 2

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi Everybody My Validation Here Allow for string and numbers and dots (.)

Now i need to add - and _ to my validation how can I do it ?

```
'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/'
```

Comment: use `\-` and `\_` to make allow in regex, check [live example](https://regex101.com/r/8Ppk2D/1)

Comment: Can you show me how can i do it in my code please

Comment: share which text you want to allow which is not allowing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to use backslash to escape a special characters in regex. so will be `\-`and `\_`.

Comment: I commented this already, can you add this suggestion in code that OP given ?

Comment: @Niklesh Raut, @Kareem Elsharkawy may give us the text as you suggested, but otherwise he can consider this little example, `2\+3=5`,without put backslash `"\"` before `+` sign, regex will define `+` as a special character as it used to indicates one or many.